# Bevel tool not working

Tags: modeling, mesh, bevel

I was trying to bevel some corner vertices on a plane mesh. I hit some key accidentally (not sure what) and now instead of shaping my corner, the bevel tool makes a grid of vertices when I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> shortcut. I'm not sure what I have done, but I'd like to undo it.

[image: Screenshot of my problem]

Comment: Can u add an image of the issue to picturise your problem?

Comment: have a look in your keymap and try and alot any other key fro beveling

Comment: Most likely you enable Only Verties mode of Boolean operation. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bevel.html#options

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 Your edit suggestion is good, but 'Bevel tool not working' is not descriptive of the problem. We probably need pictures to better understand the issue to be able to give it a better title.

Comment: Sorry and Thank you  again for the information. I will take that into consideration before editing any post on the future. I wanted to make the title smaller

Comment: back from work, now with a screenshot of my problem. ctrl+shift+B enters only vertecies mode by default. so the issue isnt that nothing is affected, but rather that where the corner of this plane would be beveled away, instead i create a grid of Vertecies and Edges that i would have to remove manually

Comment: Make sure to apply scale to the object (Object mode > select the object > Ctrl+A). Then bevel. So far seems like beveling the corner vertex should already give you smooth corner

Comment: I think that might have solved it. Beveling seems to work fine now. Thank you!